# SLinkedList object is not callable

Tags: python, spyder

I was curious why this piece of code runs well in a terminal but in spyder, it throws the error **TypeError: 'SLinkedList' object is not callable**.

```
from itertools import combinations
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
result = []
for i in range(len(l1)+1):
        c = combinations(l1, i)
        for j in c:
                #type(j) is <class 'tuple'>
                result.append(list(j)) #error on doing list(j)

print(result)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is strange. No error if you remove the `list()` call?

Comment: Please check your python version on both your `terminal` as well as `spyder` are same.

Comment: Thanks, VIAYSLN. I did not think that way. It was due to version 3.3.3 in spyder and 3.7.1 in the terminal. Shall I remove this post? At first glance this is interesting.

Comment: How did you install Spyder? If you got it with the Anaconda distribution (the recommended way) it will use Anaconda's Python by default, but if you already had a different version of Python installed on your system then that's probably what you're running from the command line.

Comment: I installed Anaconda distribution in the recommended way. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check whether you are overwriting "`list`" object somewhere else in your full source code.

```
>>> list = [1,2,3,4]
>>> tup = (1,2,3)
>>> print(list(tup))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for this post, the problem was version as you explained in comments, but this is nice suggestion.